# OpenGLES 3 Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage -6683

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I receive the CVPixelBuffer from [_videoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:[_playerItem currentTime] itemTimeForDisplay:nil]; and I transfer this pixelbuffer to CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage function to create luma texture or chrome texture

```
// Y-plane
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,_videoTextureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RED_EXT,width, height, GL_RED_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &outTexture);
if (err) {
    NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
}
```

when I use OpenGLES 2.0 ,it worked, but changed to OpenGLES 3.0,it will failed and print some errors like below:

> Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage -6683
>   Failed to create IOSurface image (texture)

OpenGLES 3.0/2.0 code:

```
_context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3];

if (!_context) {
    _context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    if (!_context) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }
    _openGLESVer = OpenGLESVersion2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using OpenGL ES 3.0, you need to replace `GL_RED_EXT` with `GL_LUMINANCE`, consider code below(I am using it in my app a year before), **it should work only the pixelBuffer is yuv420sp whether full range or video range**. Note that `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` will not work with yuv420p.

`// Y-plane
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,_videoTextureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE,width, height, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &outTexture);`

Comment: What is the constant for yuv420sp in Core Video?